# phpstorm 10 portable error

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm

In my office, there's restrictions on installing programs so I thought of searching and see if there's portable for phpstorm (even though I love sublime) but I still would like to use phpstorm instead and I went through a few sites most of them were talking about webstorm and the few talked about phpstorm mentioned downloading as zip and modify the `idea.properties` file then it should work but after editing the files I tried opening phpstorm.exe and this error message comes up

```
Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:81)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:48)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:57)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:67)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:54)
    at org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer.start(BuiltInServer.java:79)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock$2.call(SocketLock.java:133)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock$2.call(SocketLock.java:113)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.a(SocketLock.java:157)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:113)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.a(StartupUtil.java:263)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:90)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:127)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:97)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:31)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:77)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:68)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:170)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:125)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: socket
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.serverSocket(Net.java:420)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.<init>(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:88)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openServerSocketChannel(SelectorProviderImpl.java:56)
    at java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel.open(ServerSocketChannel.java:108)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:123)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:83)
    ... 34 more
```

**idea.properties file **  I uncomment four lines which are these

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE config folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
 idea.config.path=${user.home}/.WebIde/config

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE system folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
 idea.system.path=${user.home}/.WebIde/system

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to user installed plugins folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
 idea.plugins.path=${idea.config.path}/plugins

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE logs folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
 idea.log.path=${idea.system.path}/log
```

I also tried this with the idea.properties (changed $user to $idea)

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE config folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
 idea.config.path=${idea.home}/.WebIde/config

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE system folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
 idea.system.path=${idea.home}/.WebIde/system

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to user installed plugins folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
 idea.plugins.path=${idea.config.path}/plugins

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE logs folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
 idea.log.path=${idea.system.path}/log
```

Is anyone able to give me a hand how to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put here your idea.properties file.

Comment: @JoseCarlosRamosCarmenates I only added the 4 uncommented lines unless you want me to put the whole files which has quite some lines

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows, you must bear this comment, which appears in the beginning of idea.properties file:

> ## Note for Windows users: Please make sure you're using forward slashes (e.g. c:/idea/system).

You can replaced all path.

Comment: yes I did replace path like `M:/` but still getting that error I posted

Comment: Please put here your full path.

Comment: other than what I mentioned about and reminded by you, I also changed the paths like this `idea.config.path=M:/.WebIde/config`
`idea.system.path=M:/.WebIde/system`
`idea.plugins.path=M:/plugins`
`idea.log.path=M:/log` which still gives the error

Comment: You sure that  `M:/plugins` path exist intro your device `M:/`?

Comment: Yup it's a local harddrive, I even have the phpstorm folder extracted in the same drive

Comment: Add  `user.home=M:/`

Comment: where should I add it?

Comment: At first lines the idea.properties file.

Comment: still the same error but the config.path is still `idea.config.path=M:/.WebIde/config` I didn't change anything here so now I have ` user.home=M:/` `idea.config.path=M:/.WebIde/config` and the other 3 lines the same as mentioned above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102421/discussion-between-jose-carlos-ramos-carmenates-and-dora).